# Deploy AngularJS app on tomcat

Tags: angularjs, tomcat, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I created an AngularJS app with the yeoman angular generator. Now I want to host it using Apache tomcat.

I already ran "grunt build" and have all my assets ready in the "dist"-folder. Is there a way to create a .war-file or can I just copy the files to a folder inside tomcat?

Comment: Hi, I landed up on the same issue and found this post. Were you able to get this fixed? Does copying the contents in web apps dir works for you? As it messes my relative URLs for js and CSS load. did you faced this issue too?

Comment: No I just had to do a "grunt build" and copy the contents from my "dist" folder into a new folder within tomcat's "webapps" folder. If I would just copy the "dist" folder into the webapps directory I could access my app via "http://<servername>:<port>/dist"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just copy paste your all files in your project folder e.g. $TOMCAT_PATH/webapps/your-project-root/

Cheers!!

Comment: Ok, it messed up some CSS and references, but in principle this works. Thank you!

Comment: Let me if you still face any problem in future. Thanks for marking my question correct

Comment: hi Martin, how were you able to resolve the references? i tried dist/...js...but it says "failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH". thanks

Comment: is there any message about permission denied?

Comment: How we can deploy it over the network, I mean on another tomcat server?

Comment: use same tactics that you done for deploying on first tomcat

Comment: How can we deploy projects with node module dependencies.