# Angularjs app refresh with tomcat going to 404 page

Tags: angularjs, tomcat, gruntjs

I have deployed angular app in tomcat7.

What did :

```
      1 Made angular app as an html5 mode to true by adding  fallowing code in app.js

      if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        };



      2. Added  `<base href="/dist/#/">` in index.html 

      2. Build the app by using grunt `grunt build`

      3. Kept the dist into the folder `TOMCAT_HOME/webapp/ROOT`
```

Problem :

```
  1. When i refresh the page it show 404
  2. When I copy the URL and paste then also it's giving 404 error.
  3. Provide me link for tomcat configurations
```

Note :  If i hit the browser with  `Host/dist` app is running (if i navigate state by state).

Please help me where i did mistake. And how to resolve it (with tomcat sever configuration if required).

URL's I fallowed :

1. [Deploy AngularJS app on tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33785665/deploy-angularjs-app-on-tomcat)
2. http://diveintohtml5.info/examples/history/fer.html
3. [Removing the fragment identifier from AngularJS urls (# symbol)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-fragment-identifier-from-angularjs-urls-symbol)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still looking for the answer, but I will share my solution in case anyone needs it.

What I did was basically use http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/
and set the rule as

```
<rule>
<from>^/search/$</from>
<to>index.html</to>
</rule>
```

I want to point out that I used the actual file name instead of the url I want to go.

Hope this helps!

Regards,

Berkan